# Neural Network Architecture for Binary Sequential Data

Tags: neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I want to develop a neural network to generate samples of sequential binary data. For e.g. I give my network a stream of binary data: 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 (11 digits). I want my generator to be able to output some sort of similar structure to my data. Given the previous example, I want something along the lines of 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 (11 digits). From my input -> output there is similar structure in the data.

My current approach is using a GAN with with LSTM to decipher patterns. This doesn't work too well.

Obviously I would like to generate far longer streams of data but similar concept. Does anyone have any suggestions on what type of model to use. I know this is a really unconventional optimization problem but I feel like this is a necessary step in breaking down my problem.

Lastly, it might help to think about the problem like this. If I were to create a simulator to model some environment my binary string could represent the days of rain vs. no rain. Evidently, I want to generate some sort of data that is believable and matches similar patterns to the actual data.

EDIT:
I am also open to any ideas on just modeling in general like maybe using markov chains, etc.